# Why do nested flatMap calls in Java 8 require a type witness

Tags: java, java-8, type-inference

Nested flatMap calls appear not uncommonly. Consider this contrived example.

```
Collection<String> solutions = 
        Stream.of("a","b").<String>flatMap( x ->
            Stream.of(1, 2).flatMap( y ->
                Stream.of(x+y, y+x)
            )
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In Java 8 update 25 this won't compile without that regrettable type witness. Why can't the constraint that we are mapping to a stream of strings not "percolate up" from the nested flatMap call?

Comment: Compiles fine with jdk 8u40 - are you maybe using eclipse's compiler?

Comment: Compiles fine with `8u05`, `8u20` and `8u40`.

Comment: Yesterday there was a similar question; the problem was indeed Eclipse's compiler. (Eclipse has its own Java compiler, separate from the JDK compiler). Try compiling this on the command line with the JDK compiler instead of inside Eclipse.

Comment: @assylias Thanks for pointing this out. Yes, I am using the Eclipse compiler, and I'm always forgetting that it behaves differently than javac. Code does indeed coompile fine with javac.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an Eclipse compiler problem. I have filed [Bug 465859](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=465859)

Comment: Worksforme in eclipse 4.5M5

Comment: Not surprisingly, when one reads the bug report. The buggy behavior is present in 4.4.2. Starting with 4.5M3 the program is accepted by ecj.
More specifically: since bug 437444 got resolved (including the adoption of several spec changes).